# rewrite statement with JOIN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join

I have to find the names of all the Providers which have in Catalog all the auto parts that provider with id = 101 has, **using JOIN clause**. Provider id = 101 is not needed in the output.

'Providers' is the first table which contains id and nameProvider.
'Catalog' is the second table which contains id and idp (id of auto parts)

Query:

```
 select nameProvider
from Providers p
where p.id != 101
and not exists ( 
  select  idp from Catalog c1 where c1.id = 101 
    minus 
  select  idp from Catalog c2 where c2.id = p.id
  )
;
```

How could I rewrite it?

Comment: `NOT EXISTS` can be re-written to an anti join. I like `NOT EXISTS` much better than anti joins, but maybe this is the task. Another option is to `CROSS JOIN` all 101 parts with all providers, then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` their real parts and see whether you have a match for every 101 part (`COUNT(*) vs. `COUNT(own part)`).

Comment: Note: JOIN is an operator, not a clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the provider id using a `left join` and aggregation pretty easily:

```
select p.id, p.nameProvider
from catalog c join
     provider p
     on c.id = 101 and p.id <> 101 left join
     catalog c2
     on c2.idp = c.idp
group by p.id, p.nameProvider
having count(*) = count(c2.idp);
```

This basically says that all the parts ids match.